# Generics, wildcards and super/extends for interfaces

Tags: generics, interface, entity, wildcard

I have the following jpa entity inheritance hierarchy:

- abstract Account
- ChildminderAccount extends Account
- ParentAccount extends Account

I would like to have the same kind of inheritance hierarchy with my DAO interfaces i.e. three intefaces:

- AccountDAO
- ChilminderAccountDAO
- ParentAccountDAO

Here is for instance my base DAO interface which will hold methods common to both ChilminderAccountDAO and ParentAccountDAO interfaces:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.bignibou.domain.Account;

public interface AccountDAO extends CrudRepository<Account, Integer> {

    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query("UPDATE Account a SET a.accountValidated = false WHERE a.accountToken = ?1")
    int deactivateAccountFromToken(String accountToken);

    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query("UPDATE Account a SET a.accountValidated = true WHERE a.accountToken = ?1")
    int reactivateAccountFromToken(String accountToken);

    @Query("SELECT COUNT(a) FROM Account a WHERE a.accountEmailAddress = :accountEmailAddress")
    long checkIfEmailAddressAlreadyExists(@Param("accountEmailAddress") String accountEmailAddress);

    Account findByAccountToken(@Param("accountToken") String accountToken);

    Account findByAccountEmailAddress(@Param("accountEmailAddress") String accountEmailAddress);
}
```

I then tried to define my ChildminderDAO interface as follows:
`public interface ChildminderAccountDAO extends CrudRepository<? super Account, Integer>, AccountDAO` which results in:

> The type ChildminderAccountDAO cannot extend or implement
>   CrudRepository. A supertype may not specify
>   any wildcard

I also tried:
`public interface ChildminderAccountDAO extends CrudRepository<ChildminderAccount, Integer>, AccountDAO` which results in:

> The interface CrudRepository cannot be implemented more than once with
>   different  arguments: CrudRepository and 
>   CrudRepository

None works and I am not sure how to specify the generics/wildcards for my sub-interfaces so that I keep the methods common to both in the super interface and allow the sub interfaces to work with their respective types of entity i.e. ChildminderAccount and ParentAccount.

Can anyone please let me know how to define my sub interfaces?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler is being fairly clear about what's wrong here (which makes a nice change!).

Your first attempt is illegal because you can't extend a wildcarded type.

Your second attempt is illegal because you can't inherit a generic interface twice with different type bindings. Note that your `ChildminderAccountDAO` would extend both `CrudRepository<ChildminderAccount, Integer>` and `AccountDAO`, and `AccountDAO` itself extends `CrudRepository<Account, Integer>`.

The approach you need to use is to make `AccountDAO` itself generic on the type of the account. It can use its type variable in its extends clause, to extend `CrudRepository` generically. The subclasses can then bind that type parameter to definite types. Like:

```
public interface AccountDAO<A extends Account> extends CrudRepository<A, Integer>

public interface ChildminderAccountDAO extends AccountDAO<ChildminderAccount>

public interface ParentAccountDAO extends AccountDAO<ParentAccount>
```